# Is there any add-on to replace the Outlook 2007 Notes editor?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm trying to sync Palm information into Outlook 2007. The Palm Memos are mapped to Outlook's Notes. The editor provided for Notes is unbelievably primitive - the windows Notepad would be a huge improvement.  The tiny fixed window can be sized from only one corner, and there are not even any scroll bars! Palm's memo's are limited to a few K of text, but Outlook apparently doesn't intend for Notes to be more than a sentence or two.

Is there any way to replace the built in Notes editor with any 3rd party app or plug-in for Outlook so the notes could be as usable as the old Palm desktop memo?

I'm not looking for a [replacement application](https://superuser.com/questions/19115/outlook-notes-replacement-or-alternatives) like OneNote  - I need to keep the notes in Outlook because it can sync Contacts, Calendar, Tasks, and Notes with my Android device. (Deja Office). I would be delighted if I could sync OneNote with Android - then I would just eliminate the Outlook notes and use OneNote. Maybe someday that will be possible. For now, I just want to be able to edit the notes in Outlook.

Comment: It turns out there is an application to sync OneNote to Android - mobilenoter.com. It just came out, but unfortunately, the current version doesn't work very well.